# npm proxy on nexus return server error 500

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus

I'm using **nexus 3.2** and i have **npm-all** group containing **npmjs** and **npm-internal** repositories but for example when i execute `npm --loglevel info install @reactivex/rxjs` that returns this error :

> npm info it worked if it ends with ok
>   npm info using npm@3.10.3
>   npm info using node@v6.5.0
>   npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 17:31:16
>   npm http request GET http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/npm-all/@reactivex%2frxjs
>   npm http 200 http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/npm-all/@reactivex%2frxjs
>   npm info addNameTag [ '@reactivex/rxjs', 'latest' ]
>   npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 17:31:17
>   npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 17:31:17
>   npm http fetch GET http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/npm-all/@reactivex/rxjs/-/rxjs-5.1.1.tgz
>   npm http fetch 500 http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/npm-all/@reactivex/rxjs/-/rxjs-5.1.1.tgz
>   npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: server error 500

**npmjs** repository configuration :

[image]

My **.npmrc** file configuration :

```
registry=http://x.x.x.x:8081/repository/npm-all/
```

Comment: I have seen this error reported in one of the git forums.. Can you please try adding `151.101.36.162 registry.npmjs.com
151.101.36.162 registry.npmjs.org` to your `hosts` file?

Comment: David can you post a link to the error in the forums? I'm interested in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding these privileges to anonymes users :

- nx-repository-view-npm-*-read
- nx-repository-view-npm-*-browse